# What does $$ in javascript of Magento 2 mean?

Tags: magento2, javascript, jquery

In some core Magento modules I see the `$$` signs used constantly when selecting an element. For example, in just 10 lines of code I have the following different selectors:

1. `$('selection-apparently-a-custom-element')`
2. `$$('#some-element-id')`
3. `jQuery('#another-element-id')`

What is the point of this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is still some prototype.js left over from Magento 1, now mixed with jQuery (in noConflict mode)

That means:

- `$` is the prototype selector that returns one element by its id
- `$$` is the prototype selector that returns an array of elements by CSS selector
- `jQuery` is what would be `$` in a pure jQuery environment and returns a jQuery wrapper for an element by CSS selector